# timeformat in d3.js not working

Tags: d3.js

I am using the following code to get the hour and minute in d3.js

```
e.time=e.time.substring(12,19);
var timeformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M").parse;
e.time2=timeformat(e.time);
console.log(e.time2);
```

But I am getting null in output. My e.time contains following pattern of value

```
2015-03-29T20:32:24Z
e.time.substring(12,19) returns 20:32:24.
```

What is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things here:

1. Parse the string `20:32:24`, to a date. For that use:

   ```
   var timeformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;
   ```
2. Format the Date, returning a string in the valid format )in this case hh:mm:

   ```
   var hoursandminsformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M");
   ```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/mwvvuazz/

A better approach, rather than using `e.time.substring(12,19);`, would be just to parse the full date object using:

```
var ISO8601format=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

and then

```
var fomatted_time = hoursandminsformat(ISO8601format.parse("2015-03-29T20:32:24Z"));
```